# How to load Js file dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I am developing ajax based website and I am using PHP,Smarty & Jquery. For js & CSS file, I am using caching functionality. So I need to load function related js file dynamically trough run-time when Ajax is called. I don't want to load them in HTML statically. Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's getScript function like this:

```
$.getScript("yourscript.js", function(){
    console.log("script loaded");
});
```

**jQuery Documentation:** https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadJS('your_file.js');
});
function loadJS(file) {
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    jsElm.src = file;
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}
</script>
```